# Unable to fix the image on top in TD tag

Tags: html, css

I have requirement to have image and image content in a table .And the problem is my content for the image is very long and I am loosing the grip of image location in the td tag  and image is settling down in center .Can anyone please help me out of this by reviewing below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Cell that spans two rows:</h2>
<table style="width:100%">
 
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2"><article>“Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain competitors may be the only sustainable competitive advantageSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.”
… Arie De Geus, former head of Strategic Planning at Royal Dutch Shell.

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p>

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p> 

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p>

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain!</p>
Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain<p><br>

<br>

- Spectacular Mountain<br>
Spectacular Mountain<br>
<br>
mycompay@microsoft.com<br>
 </article></th>
    <td>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td><h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:115px;height:115px;"> </td>
   
    </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Cell that spans two rows:</h2>
<table style="width:100%">
 
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2"><article>“Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain competitors may be the only sustainable competitive advantageSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.”
… Arie De Geus, former head of Strategic Planning at Royal Dutch Shell.

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p>

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p> 

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p>

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain!</p>
Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain<p><br>

<br>

- Spectacular Mountain<br>
Spectacular Mountain<br>
<br>
mycompay@microsoft.com<br>
 </article></th>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td><h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:115px;height:115px;"> </td>
   
    </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming you want the "mountain view" cell to be top aligned.

```
td.image {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vertical-align:top` will fix the problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Cell that spans two rows:</h2>
<table style="width:100%">
 
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2"><article>“Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain competitors may be the only sustainable competitive advantageSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.”
… Arie De Geus, former head of Strategic Planning at Royal Dutch Shell.

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p>

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p> 

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.</p>

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain!</p>
Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain.

<p>Spectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular MountainSpectacular Mountain<p><br>

<br>

- Spectacular Mountain<br>
Spectacular Mountain<br>
<br>
mycompay@microsoft.com<br>
 </article></th>
    <td>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td><h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:115px;height:115px;"> </td>
   
    </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```